# C<T> derived from T, is it safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I have a problem that can be solved nicely if I can indicate a base class (`C derived from T`) for a certain class `C<T>`.

I have never done like this before, so I create a short test case and [it works](http://ideone.com/VPHyVJ).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B{
    public: int k=5;
};
template<class T> class C : public T{};

int main() {
    C<B> c;
    std::cout<<c.k<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Question**

Is it on the edge of C++ syntax?   / Is it implemention-defined?
Is it safe to use in real business?
Is there anything I should concern specifically? (I hope there is none.)
What is this technique called (if any)?

Comment: FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @Nicky C  Thank!  Wow it is widely use!

Comment: @NickyC: Which is a pattern where the base recieves the derived class as a template parameter. Deriving from a template paramter isn't quite the same.

Comment: @Pixelchemist That's why it is just an FYI.

Comment: Well if there were concerns about this use the compiler would say something.

Comment: @javaLover Actually, CRTP is the reverse of your case. But it shows you template and class inheritance combine quite nicely/curiously.

Comment: This looks similar to, but is bit different than the CRTP which has the pattern `class D : public B<D>` so that the base class can use functionality of the derived class.

Comment: @Havenard: there are many things in C++ that the compiler will allow (and may even be legal, valid code) that would be cause for concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not '*on the edge of C++*' but perfectly legit if `T` is a type one can derive from. I don't know of any specific name for this "pattern".

*Note that you can either derive from `std::remove_reference_t<T>` instead (in order to make things like `C<B&>` valid) or leave it `T` in order to make the compilation fail for `C<B&>` and thelike - it depends.*

Comment: Can you also answer the last question?  XD

Comment: @javaLover: It has no name. The CRTP is the *opposite* of what you're doing. In the CRTP, your type `T` derives from `C<T>`.

Comment: @NicolBolas It has a name, isn't it a mixin in its simplest form?

Comment: @skypjack Thank. agree (+ [this drdobbs reference](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/mixin-based-programming-in-c/184404445) ).  You can post it as a solution (for the last unanswered question) if you want.  If so, I will upvote it. :)

Comment: @javaLover I'm not looking for reputation on SO, it would worth it if Pixelchemist added the name to its answer. Try to ping him. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack: But it's not a mixin yet, because it doesn't forward construction through to the base class. At best, it is *part* of a mixin.

Comment: @NicolBolas I could argue that it has an implicit default constructor, therefore construction is implicitly forwarded through the base class. Anyway an _almost-mixin_ sounds good for it. :-)